# DOMContentLoaded and DOM tree

Tags: javascript, dom

I want a **definite and reliable** answer to the following question: 
Does `DOMContentLoaded` event fires when `DOM tree has been completely built`? My answer is yes, 99%. I want to be sure 100%.

Comment: Is there some reason you can just look at the documentation for yourself?

Comment: See the [spec (and particularly 8.2.6)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#parsing-html-documents)

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) says:

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

Notice the word **completely**, that should give you the missing 1%  ;)